# Java SimpleDateFormat not accepting ##/##

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Below, I've got the code I'm trying to use. It always hits the catch, returning a null. Both month and day are integers, and they've already been checked to ensure they fall within existing dates on existing days. Regardless, I'm testing with "05" for the month and "02" for the day. Does an input of ##/## not work, for some reason?

```
public static Date getAlphabetDate()
{
    try
    {
        String tempDate = month + "/" + day;
        Date alphabetDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d").parse(tempDate);
        return alphabetDate;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm trying to format this output so it looks like "May 02". When I look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), I see a huge section of the page is dedicated to formatting output. Why isn't mine formatting like that?

Comment: `month + "/" + day` != `MMMM d`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is `02/05`, you should use the corresponding date format:

```
public static Date getAlphabetDate()
{
    try
    {
        String tempDate = month + "/" + day;
        Date alphabetDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd").parse(tempDate);
        return alphabetDate;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that made it so I'm at least getting a date... When I look at the documentation, though, it looks like all I need is "M/d". If I want my output to look like "May 02", how would I modify this?

Comment: @DanCallahan Use another `DateFormatter` that meets those requirements.  `Date` does not have a concept of a format of it's own (beyond what the default local is telling it)

Comment: EDIT: that doesn't make sense... the documentation for SimpleDateFormat specifically states that you can edit the output. Am I crazy or something?

Answer (score 1):

you are parsing the string in the simpledataformat the wrongway..

**try this:**

```
String tempDate = month + "/" + day;
        Date alphabetDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/d").parse(tempDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input doesn't match your format pattern...

Your input is in the form of `MM/dd` but you pattern is in the format of `MMMM d`, you will need to make one of these match

Try using

```
String tempDate = month + " " + day;
Date alphabetDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM d").parse(tempDate);
```

Instead, for example...